# javafx8 application executable

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8

I have created a media player in Eclipse using `javafx8`. The jar file is generated correctly but when I run the executable file, the following message appear

[image: i get this when i run the app]

Here is my `build.xml`. I have tried to do some modifications but it is not working. I'm using `jdk.1.8.0`

```
    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="\Android programming\PiliPlayer">
            <filename name="images"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="D:\Android programming\PiliPlayer">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="images"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="PiliPlayer.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="PILI PLAYER"
        mainClass="application.VedaPlayer"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/PiliPlayer.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="PlLI AND VEDA"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="PILI PLAYER"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="Pili Player" nativeBundles="msi"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="Pili Player" vendor="PlLI AND VEDA"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Too less information to give a precise answer, but you could try to implement logging in your main class, so you can look in your log file, what kind of Exception is thrown and why.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog indicates that an exception occurred in your main class. Are you catching all possible exceptions that the main class could throw? If no exceptions are generated in the IDE, you may want to check that all external libraries and resources are on the classpath.